# What is Donor's adjusted basis of gift?

Tags: united-states, taxes, gift-tax

What would the "Donor's adjusted basis of gift" be for a money gift? Would it be the same as the value of the money sent? I'm filling out form 709 Schedule A, Part 1, column D and I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [instructions for form 709](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i709.pdf):

> **Column D. Donor's Adjusted Basis of Gifts**
>
> Show the basis you would use for income tax purposes if the gift were
>   sold or exchanged. Generally, this means cost plus improvements, less
>   applicable depreciation, amortization, and depletion.
>
> For more information on adjusted basis, see Pub. 551, Basis of Assets.

Unless that cash is a collectible, then column D for cash would be the same as Column F Value at Date of Gift.